# Ajax get request returns entire page instead of controller method

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I writing a script to poll a mysql table but instead of returning what the method has,it returns the entire page html page calling  ajax from

This is **my ajax**

```
var base_url = '<?php base_url('index.php / enterprise / poll_send_q '); ?>';
/**
    Send Queue Poll
*/
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: base_url,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#send_q_poll').text(data);
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

and this is my **controller method**

```
 public function poll_send_q(){
  if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
                redirect('enterprise/derEintrag');
  }
  $le_current_logged_in = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id(); 
  $this->db->where('user_id', $le_current_logged_in);
  $this->db->from('send_q');
  $all = $this->db->count_all_results();
  echo $all;
}
```

What could be the reason for the script not returning the number of rows from the controller method?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing echo here

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url('index.php/enterprise/poll_send_q'); ?>';
```